# How to grep a matching filename AND extension from pattern file to a text file?

Tags: grep

### Content of testfile.txt

```
/path1/abc.txt
/path2/abc.txt.1
/path3/abc.txt123
```

### Content of pattern.txt

```
abc.txt$
```

### Bash Command

```
grep -i -f pattern.txt testfile.txt
```

Output:

```
/path1/abc.txt
```

This is a working solution, but currently the `$` in the pattern is manually added to each line and this edited pattern file is uploaded to users. I am trying to avoid the manual amendment.

Alternate solution to loop and read line by line, but required scripting skills or upload scripts to user environment.

Want to keep the original pattern files in an audited environment, users just login and run simple cut-n-paste commands.

Any one liner solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't just having them run `grep '/abc\.txt$' testfile.txt` work?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP mentions "manually added to each line" so I think the question has only a minimal example

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks. I wasn't clear. I though he meant he needed to add to each line in `pattern.txt` and I presumed that was to anchor `.txt` to the end so that line would be selected when used as a pattern with `-f patternfile`. I was focused on doing it without the need for a `patternfile`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to add `$` to `pattern.txt` and then use `grep`, but you might run into issues due to regexp metacharacters like the `.` character. For example, `abc.txt$` will also match `abc1txt`. And unless you take care of matching only the basename from the file path, `abc.txt$` will also match `/some/path/foobazabc.txt`.

I'd suggest to use `awk` instead:

```sh
$ awk '!f{a[$0]; next} $NF in a' pattern.txt f=1 FS='/' testfile.txt
/path1/abc.txt
```

- `pattern.txt f=1 FS='/' testfile.txt` here a flag `f` is set between the two files and field separator is also changed to `/` for the second file
- `!f{a[$0]; next}` if flag `f` is not set (i.e. for the first file), build an array `a` with line contents as the key
- `$NF in a` for the second file, if the last field matches a key in array `a`, print the line

Just noticed that you are also using `-i` option, so use this for case insensitive matching:

```sh
awk '!f{a[tolower($0)]; next} tolower($NF) in a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pattern.txt contains only a single pattern, and you don't want to change it, since it is an audited file, you could do

```
grep -i -f "$(<pattern.txt)'$' testfile.txt
```

instead. Note that this would break, if the maintainer of the file one day decided to actually write there a terminating $.

IMO, it would make more sense to explain to the maintainer of pattern.txt that he is supposed to place there a simple regular expression, which is going to match your testfile. In this case s/he can decide whether the pattern really should match only the right edge or some inner part of the lines.

If pattern.txt contains more than one line, and you want to add the `$` to each line, you can likewise do a

```
grep -i -f <(sed 's/$/$/' <pattern.txt) testfile.txt
```

Comment: OP mentions "manually added to each line" so I think the question has only a minimal example

Comment: I see. I understood it in the sense of _every time a new pattern file is uploaded_.

Comment: @Sundeep : Amended my answer. Does it look reasonable now?

Comment: Since `-f` expects a file, you'd need `<(sed 's/$/$/' <pattern.txt)`... see my answer's first para for possible issues with this approach

Answer (score 0):

As the '$' symbol indicates pattern end. The following script should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_pattern='pattern.txt' # path to pattern file
file_test='testfile.txt' # path to test file

while IFS=$ read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    grep -wn "$line" $file_test
done < "$file_pattern"
```

- You can remove the IFS descriptor if the pattern file comes with leading/trailing spaces.
- Also the grep option -w matches only whole word and -n provides with line number.